# Oreo Hidl-gen build

Tags: android, hal

I have been trying to build hidl-gen using the command

I tried the following

```
 PACKAGE=android.hardware.nfc@1.0

 LOC=hardware/interfaces/nfc/1.0/default/

 m -j hidl-gen

 hidl-gen -o $LOC -Lc++-impl -randroid.hardware:hardware/interfaces \

     -randroid.hidl:system/libhidl/transport $PACKAGE

 hidl-gen -o $LOC -Landroidbp-impl -randroid.hardware:hardware/interfaces \

     -randroid.hidl:system/libhidl/transport $PACKAGE
```

and got the error message: No rule to make hidl-gen. I need some help to build this tool to generate the hidl stubs for my own binderized HAL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script from the top most directory of your android source. Worked for me.

Comment: this should be in comment

Comment: I tried to add comment. But I don't have 50 reps to post it in comments. That's why put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `m` from any directory in the source tree. No need to go to top. Maybe your android does not yet have `hidl-gen` because it is older than Android 8?

If you are working with Androis 8 or newer, you can search for the module definition with

```sh
mgrep hidl-gen
```

It should find the module in `system/tools/hidl`.